# InputField - change text alignment to center

Tags: dynamic, formatting, gui-construction, inputfield, alignment

Is it possible to align text in InputField Right/Centered?
(Seems Left is default)

Seems there is no alignment option for InputField.

What I want is center - More specifically, Real-time centered : I mean the text should be aligned centered even when typing something in the input field.

In every examples shown in the MMA help, it is aligned Left. Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `InputField` has the option `Alignment`:

```
Options[InputField] // Short
```

> [image: out]

And it works as expected:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], Alignment -> Center]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for `Options[InputField]`!